# Problema en plantila Ansible con bucles for

Tags: bucle-for, ansible

Estoy trabajando con Ansible y necesito mostrar una lista de las interfaces de red de los host. En una plantilla con formato Jinja2 necesito los siguientes valores: Nombre, IP, Mascara y Red para cada una de las interfaces.
Para tener esta información utilizo los ansible_facts pero tengo un problema a la hora de hacer los for.

Las interfaces de red las saco de aquí:

```
 "ansible_interfaces": [
        "eth1",
        "eth0",
        "lo"
    ],
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, hago un for y me muestra las tres. Mi problema viene que la información que necesito de cada interfaz esta separada en el jason:

```
 "ansible_eth0": {
        "active": true,
        "device": "eth0",
        "features": {
            "esp_hw_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "esp_tx_csum_hw_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "fcoe_mtu": "off [fixed]",
            "generic_receive_offload": "on",
            "generic_segmentation_offload": "on",
            "highdma": "on [fixed]",
            "hw_tc_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "l2_fwd_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "large_receive_offload": "on",
            "loopback": "off [fixed]",
            "netns_local": "off [fixed]",
            "ntuple_filters": "off [fixed]",
            "receive_hashing": "off [fixed]",
            "rx_all": "off [fixed]",
            "rx_checksumming": "on [fixed]",
            "rx_fcs": "off [fixed]",
            "rx_gro_hw": "off [fixed]",
            "rx_udp_tunnel_port_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "rx_vlan_filter": "on [fixed]",
            "rx_vlan_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "rx_vlan_stag_filter": "off [fixed]",
            "rx_vlan_stag_hw_parse": "off [fixed]",
            "scatter_gather": "on",
            "tcp_segmentation_offload": "on",
            "tls_hw_record": "off [fixed]",
            "tls_hw_rx_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "tls_hw_tx_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_checksum_fcoe_crc": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_checksum_ip_generic": "on",
            "tx_checksum_ipv4": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_checksum_ipv6": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_checksum_sctp": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_checksumming": "on",
            "tx_esp_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_fcoe_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_gre_csum_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_gre_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_gso_partial": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_gso_robust": "on [fixed]",
            "tx_ipxip4_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_ipxip6_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_lockless": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_nocache_copy": "off",
            "tx_scatter_gather": "on",
            "tx_scatter_gather_fraglist": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_sctp_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_tcp6_segmentation": "on",
            "tx_tcp_ecn_segmentation": "on",
            "tx_tcp_mangleid_segmentation": "off",
            "tx_tcp_segmentation": "on",
            "tx_udp_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_udp_tnl_csum_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_udp_tnl_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_vlan_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_vlan_stag_hw_insert": "off [fixed]",
            "vlan_challenged": "off [fixed]"
        },
        "hw_timestamp_filters": [],
        "ipv4": {
            "address": "x.x.x.x",
            "broadcast": "x.x.x.x",
            "netmask": "255.255.192.0",
            "network": "x.x.x.x"
        },
        "ipv4_secondaries": [
            {
                "address": "x.x.x.x",
                "broadcast": "x.x.x.x",
                "netmask": "255.255.0.0",
                "network": "x.x.x.x"
            }
        ],
        "ipv6": [
            {
                "address": "",
                "prefix": "64",
                "scope": "link"
            }
        ],
        "macaddress": "",
        "module": "virtio_net",
        "mtu": 1500,
        "pciid": "virtio0",
        "promisc": false,
        "speed": -1,
        "timestamping": [
            "tx_software",
            "rx_software",
            "software"
        ],
        "type": "ether"
    },
    "ansible_eth1": {
        "active": true,
        "device": "eth1",
        "features": {
            "esp_hw_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "esp_tx_csum_hw_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "fcoe_mtu": "off [fixed]",
            "generic_receive_offload": "on",
            "generic_segmentation_offload": "on",
            "highdma": "on [fixed]",
            "hw_tc_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "l2_fwd_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "large_receive_offload": "on",
            "loopback": "off [fixed]",
            "netns_local": "off [fixed]",
            "ntuple_filters": "off [fixed]",
            "receive_hashing": "off [fixed]",
            "rx_all": "off [fixed]",
            "rx_checksumming": "on [fixed]",
            "rx_fcs": "off [fixed]",
            "rx_gro_hw": "off [fixed]",
            "rx_udp_tunnel_port_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "rx_vlan_filter": "on [fixed]",
            "rx_vlan_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "rx_vlan_stag_filter": "off [fixed]",
            "rx_vlan_stag_hw_parse": "off [fixed]",
            "scatter_gather": "on",
            "tcp_segmentation_offload": "on",
            "tls_hw_record": "off [fixed]",
            "tls_hw_rx_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "tls_hw_tx_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_checksum_fcoe_crc": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_checksum_ip_generic": "on",
            "tx_checksum_ipv4": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_checksum_ipv6": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_checksum_sctp": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_checksumming": "on",
            "tx_esp_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_fcoe_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_gre_csum_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_gre_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_gso_partial": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_gso_robust": "on [fixed]",
            "tx_ipxip4_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_ipxip6_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_lockless": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_nocache_copy": "off",
            "tx_scatter_gather": "on",
            "tx_scatter_gather_fraglist": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_sctp_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_tcp6_segmentation": "on",
            "tx_tcp_ecn_segmentation": "on",
            "tx_tcp_mangleid_segmentation": "off",
            "tx_tcp_segmentation": "on",
            "tx_udp_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_udp_tnl_csum_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_udp_tnl_segmentation": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_vlan_offload": "off [fixed]",
            "tx_vlan_stag_hw_insert": "off [fixed]",
            "vlan_challenged": "off [fixed]"
        },
        "hw_timestamp_filters": [],
        "ipv4": {
            "address": "x.x.x.x",
            "broadcast": "x.x.x.x",
            "netmask": "255.255.240.0",
            "network": "x.x.x.x"
        },
        "ipv6": [
            {
                "address": "",
                "prefix": "64",
                "scope": "link"
            }
        ],
        "macaddress": "",
        "module": "virtio_net",
        "mtu": 1500,
        "pciid": "virtio1",
        "promisc": false,
        "speed": -1,
        "timestamping": [
            "tx_software",
            "rx_software",
            "software"
        ],
        "type": "ether"
    },
```

Para conseguir esta información lo intento de la siguiente manera:

```
{{% for interfaz in ansible_interfaces %}}
{{% for item in ansible_['interfaz'] %}}
Nombre: {{ item.device }}
IP: {{ item.ipv4.address }}
Mascara de red: {{ item.ipv4.metmask }}
Red: {{ item.ipv4.network }}
{{% endfor %}}
{{% endfor %}}
```

Lo he probado de diferentes maneras y no consigo la forma de hacerlo. En mi opinión lo que me devuelve el for es un string. E probado con la opción iteritems pero tampoco lo consigo.
Si alguien me puede ayudar con el problema se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta a mi cuestion es la siguiente:

```
{% for i in ansible_interfaces %}
{% set dev = lookup('vars', 'ansible_' ~ i) %}

Name: {{ dev.device }}
IP: {{ dev.ipv4.address|default(None) }}
Netmask: {{ dev.ipv4.netmask|default(None) }}
Red: {{ dev.ipv4.network|default(None) }}

{% endfor %}
```